# Smoothing out DensityPlot3D over a region quickly

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, graphics3d, regions

Is there a way to smooth out `DensityPlot3D` over a region quickly in an aesthetic way? I can set `PlotPoints` to 100 or even 200, but this is very slow and sometimes still produces jagged edges. Since this region is very simple I wonder if there is builtin smoothing for Basic Geometric Regions.

Example:

```
DensityPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 3], PlotPoints -> 50]`
```

[image]

Above, with `PlotPoints->200` (much nicer, but takes several minutes on my laptop):

[image]

I don't know if this is an intended consequence or not, but I can't even make out the blue area in the center.

For comparison, 2D `DensityPlot` still shows aliasing, but it's minimal and extremely fast:

```
DensityPlot[x + y, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

[image]